# Is there a way to get the field definitions of a table-valued parameter in c#

Tags: c#

We have a generic application that dynamically maps values to an object or table, and I want to write a generic way to validate these values against the fields defined in a table-valued parameter.  Is there a way to dynamically get the field definitions in a table-valued parameter in c#, please?

---

I am using plain ADO, .Net 4.5, VS 2013.

I do not have any code so far because I don't see a way to accomplish this?  The current issue that made me think of this, is that we had a string value that was too long for a varchar field in the TVP.  The standard exception about truncating occurs, and I'd like to find a way to avoid this issue in the first place.

---

I guess I can call this query to get what I'm after, but was hoping I could get it some other way?

```
DECLARE @TvpName VARCHAR(256)

SET @TvpName = 'MyTableTypeName'

SELECT o.NAME AS 'TVP'
    ,c.column_id
    ,c.NAME
    ,c.system_type_id
    ,t.NAME AS DataTypeName
    ,c.max_length
    ,c.precision
    ,c.scale
    ,c.is_nullable
    ,c.object_id
FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON o.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
    ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE (o.type = 'TT') --    Only lookup User Defined Table Types
    AND (o.NAME LIKE '%' + @TvpName + '%')
ORDER BY o.NAME
    ,c.column_id
```

Comment: Can you add **more details** around your question? like What Provider you're using EF/Plain ADO and some sample code snippets What have you tried so far.

Comment: Add some code so we can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate all columns in `DataTable` and get type information:

```
foreach (var column in dbTable.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(column.DataType);
    Console.WriteLine(column.DefaultValue);
    Console.WriteLine(column.AutoIncrement);
    Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    Console.WriteLine(column.MaxLength);
    Console.WriteLine(column.Table);
}
```